# How to create a custom button for Facebook places?

Tags: facebook

Is there a 3rd party software program for developing features around Facebook places? I would like to develop something specifically for like the highlighted button in the included picture:

[image]

We would like to bring in external html hosted on our site into a customized button. To be honest, I think I've seen this on certain places sites but I don't see in their docs where this can be done anymore. We would have a bunch of sites so looking into possible 3rd party solutions. Perhaps it doesn't exist but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Developer Tools](https://developers.facebook.com/)
You have to do the programming yourself; They have a few different APIs available depending on exactly what you want to do.

Here's a screenie: to get that dialogue click apps->create new app.
[image]

I'd suggest starting by reading their documentation and then just start playing with it. Of course if you run into issues [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) would be a good place to ask but not here.

Comment: but that's for a new app; I'm talking about customozing a places page. Is that possible? Or is there ideally a third party site that has a cms for managing? I read through the docs (which really suck) and couldn't tell whether what I wanted to do was even supported.

Comment: @timpone Note in the screenshot teh category selected is 'apps for pages' that lets you sandbox your own content into facebook pages subpage. Unfortunately I have to agree the docs do suck but this ain't the place to work around that. AFAIK there isn't any CMS type things available - i.e. you'll have to do all your own coding from scratch basically.